# Flutter : Animate underlining of selected text in a list view of text

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Given this example :

[image: Horizontal Listview showing tags]

It's an horizontal `ListView` showing tags. Whenever the user swipes it, it shows more tags, whenever the user taps a tag, it highlights that tag by underlining it. Right now, if you tap another tag, I animate the underlining opacity to 0 in the deselected tag, and to 1 in the newly selected tag.

I'd like the underlining to *move* from the deselected to the newly selected. I searched for a while, and didn't find a solution. I may have used inadequates keywords during my searches. Any hints on what I should use to achieve that ?

Comment: It's useless, because it can't achieve what I'd like to do. Right now, I have a `AnimatedContainer` with a bottom border with a transparent color or a black color. They are all independent, on for each tag.

Comment: how about using `CarouselSlider` or `scroll_to_index`